# Load Score app facebook unity

Tags: android, native, facebook-unity-sdk

Help me!

I load score player in app Facebook.

I use the following code:

```
FB.API("/" + FB.UserId + "/scores", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, OnLoaPlayrScoresComplete);
```

`Data` does not have score, only `name` and `id` do.

In https://developers.facebook.com, I've set PERMISSIONS : publish_actions.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be a best answer. But, you can try this.

```
FB.API("/" + FB.UserId + "/scores?fields=score", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, OnLoaPlayrScoresComplete);
```

Or you can try it yourself in [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)

From comment, here is how to post score:

```
FB.API("/" + FB.UserId + "/scores?score="+YOUR_SCORE, Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, callback);
```

Comment: tks ArAui
 but , score always returns 0 if

FB.API("/" + FB.UserId + "/scores?fields=score", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, OnLoaPlayrScoresComplete);

Comment: @LKIT So, please post score to facebook graph api first!! for example, when player finish game or gameover, the score will be posted to facebook'score. Then, you can load the score by /scores api.